Create a mosaic with display grid
I'm trying to create a responsive grid with rows with several alternating columns. Let me explain better, one row must have three columns and the next row must have two columns and so on. I need to achieve this effect with display grid. I'll write you the CSS code as it is written now
Goal
.rowsContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 186px);
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    grid-column-gap: 1rem;
    grid-row-gap: 1rem;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.card{
    width: 190px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.horizontal{
  height: 159px !important; 
}
.vertical{
  height: 243px !important;
}

I tried with flexbox and succeeded, but I necessarily have to do it with grid display

You can adopt a 6 columns layout for your grid and then use css rules that will target the 4th and 5th .card (every 5) styling them as 3 columns wide (2 per row) instead of 2 columns wide (3 per row).


.container {
  display: grid;      
  grid: auto / repeat(6, 1fr); /* 6 cols layout */
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.card {
  border: solid 1px;  
  text-align: center;
  
  grid-column: span 2; /* spans for 2 cols - 3 per row */
  height: 243px !important;
  
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px white;
}

/* each .card being the 4th and 5th each cycle */
.card:nth-child(5n),
.card:nth-child(5n-1) {  
  grid-column: span 3;  /* spans for 3 cols - 2 per row */
  height: 159px !important; 
}
<div class="container">

  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  
  <div class="card"></div>  
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>

</div>



